# Who wrote "Pate de Fois Gras"?

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

It appeared in Analog decades ago. Memorable lines included...

> *"It's the goose! The goose who laid the golden egg!"*

and

> *"That goose is a living nuclear reactor."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The author was none other than Isaac Asimov himself:

> **[Pâté de Foie Gras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A2t%C3%A9_de_Foie_Gras_(short_story))** is a science fiction short story by Isaac Asimov
>   which was first published in the September 1956 issue of Astounding
>   Science Fiction. It appeared in Asimov's 1957 science essay collection
>   Only a Trillion, in his 1968 short story collection Asimov's
>   Mysteries, and in The Complete Stories, Vol. 2. It also appeared in
>   The Edge of Tomorrow. - <sub><sup>[wikiepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A2t%C3%A9_de_Foie_Gras_(short_story))</sup></sub>

and to quote from the story:

> *There's no doubt about it,' said Billings.*
>
> *He snapped his pencil and stood up. **That Goose is a living nuclear
>   reactor.'***